Cloud CDN Signed URL: Your client does not have permission to get URL /pathToFile/sample.mp3 from this server
I am using Cloud CDN to serve files privately to my app. My app calls a cloud function which will generate the signed URL and return it for access. My load balancer is connected with a backend bucket. I am using the below script to sign the url:
const url = new URL(`https://cdn.mydomain.com/${filePathAndName}`);
      const expires = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 60; //expires in 60 seconds

      const urlToSign = `${url.pathname}?Expires=${expires}&KeyName=key1`;
      const signature = crypto
        .createHmac("sha1", Buffer.from("generatedKey", "base64"))
        .update(urlToSign)
        .digest("base64")
        .replace(/\+/g, "-")
        .replace(/\//g, "_")
        .replace(/=+$/, "");

      url.searchParams.append("Expires", expires.toString());
      url.searchParams.append("KeyName", "key1");
      url.searchParams.append("Signature", signature);

      response.json({ url: url.toString()});

Then when I try to access the link, it throws the error
Your client does not have permission to get URL /pathToFile/sample.mp3 from this server.

Does anyone know how to fix this? My bucket is private, but I granted viewer permissions to the CDN service account. If I am signing the url with the key I generated (key1), shouldn't anyone be able to access the file for as long as the link is valid?
Thank you in advance!

I managed to fix this. The fact my bucket is private and has prevent public access enabled was not the problem. I ensured the CDN's service account was added as Storage Object Viewer so the CDN can access the bucket. The problem with my signed link was the urlToSign variable.
const urlToSign = `${url.pathname}?Expires=${expires}&KeyName=key1`;

The above generated a url like this: /pathToFile/sample.mp3?Expires=1734744212&KeyName=key1 but the url that you sign needs to match the final url and it must include even the https:// portion.
Therefore, all I had to do to make this work was change the urlToSign variable to
const urlToSign = `https://cdn.mydomain.com${url.pathname}?Expires=${expires}&KeyName=key1`;

I hope this helps other people who may run into the same problem. The signing is very sensitive so make sure every single character is accurate. It can't even have an extra / or anything different to the final URL. urlToSign needs to look identical to the final url, but without the signature parameter which is added at the end.

Add code to show how you generated this: Buffer.from("generatedKey", "base64").

The key is generated in the console when you're setting up the load balancer. There's probably a way to do it through code, maybe with gsutil.
